# Рассылка по e-mail в высоконагруженном проекте

Tags: рассылка, регистрация, email

Добрый день, задача следующая:
Имеется сайт на котором проходит порядка 5 регистраций в секунду.
Всем зарегистрировавшимся необходимо отправить сообщение по e-mail с ссылкой подтверждения.
В наличии: свой SMTP-сервер, PHP, MySQL

Мое виденье данного процесса следующие:
Обрабатываем регистрации пользователей, заносим в БД ключ подтверждения, наряду с остальными данными пользователя.
Потом раз к примеру в секунд 10 выберем свежеиспечённых юзеров по наличию этого ключа,
И рассылаем сообщения по SMTP (по сокету, перечисляя в запросе получателей).
При подтверждении ключ затираем, registration is completed!

Хотелось бы услышать мнения и рекомендации для оптимизации данного подхода, а так же возможные пути решения задачи.

Comment: Отлично заданный вопрос.

Comment: Сделал на двух таблицах, т.к. в перспективе будут и другие уведомления. Пароль вносится сразу, использую отдельный статус для пользователя. По умолчанию 0. Активен 1, дальше модераторы, админы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я обычно делаю три поля: *КлючПотверждения*, *НовыйПароль*, *БылоЛиПисьмо*. Объясняю зачем.

Для нового пользователя в поле *Пароль* ставится "*", заполняется* НовыйПароль*,* БылоЛиПисьмо* = 0.

- Отправлялка делает запрос везде, где *БылоЛиПисьмо* = 0.
- И для них сразу делает апдейт *БылоЛиПисьмо* = 1.
- После успешной отправки письма, делается *БылоЛиПисьмо* = 2.
- Если была ошибка отправки - *БылоЛиПисьмо* = 3, или письмо вернулось с отлупом *БылоЛиПисьмо* = 4 (мониторится по РОРу).

Эта таблица периодическим кем-то мониторится, чистится. БылоЛиПисьмо == 3 раз в несколько часов отправляется, пока не пройдут сутки с момент регистрации, потом ставится как отлуп.

При нажатии ссылки с ключем -> *Пароль* = *НовыйПароль*. *КлючПотверждения* = пусто, *НовыйПароль* = пусто.

При сбросе пароля заполняется *НовыйПароль* и *КлючПотверждения*.

Если в БД *Пароль* = "*" пишем пользователю, что учетка не активирована.

Comment: Есть, что почерпнуть. Вообще мне сейчас думается вынести всё это в отдельую таблицу. Я имею ввиду касательно отправки.

Comment: Это тоже делали, правда тогда ваяли службу е-майл рассылки - каждое письмо было отдельной записью в БД. 

Подтверждения регистрации кидались в общую таблицу тоже, но с более высоким приоритетом (чем обычные письма рассылки) и поэтому уходили очень быстро.

Так как у вас только регистрация - то очень крайней необходимости в отдельной таблице нет.

Comment: еще бы хорошо разделить отправку писем по разным серверам (ip) чтоб не блочили как спам

Comment: SilverIce - круто!

Comment: 2dfhsfhgfj. Одна БД - десять серверов-обработчиков - никто ж не мешает.
Но можно нарваться на дурной байес, который решит, что раз у вас 10 серверов - ты вы наглый спамер и зарежет начисто.

Подпись с возможностью отписки в каждом письме. Нормальная поинтер-запись для сервер, чтоб обратный резольв работал. Отправка писем от существующего пользователя. В принципе будет достаточно сухо.